# Selected input text by default (focus) in ContextMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I have a text field generated by contextmenu, and I want it to be selected by default (autofocus by default). I do not succeed with the function jquery focus [$ ('. classInput'). focus ()]

```
$(function(){
        $.contextMenu({
            selector: '.input-context-menu', 
            items: {
                // <input type="text">
                name_input: {
                    name: "Name input :", 
                    type: 'text', 
                    value: "value_input",
                    events: {
                        keyup: function(e) {
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `focus` in the `events.show` section.
You'll need `timeout` to let the `input` element appear in the DOM before setting `focus`.
The `input` name will be prefixed with `context-menu-input-`.

See the snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    items: {
      // <input type="text">
      input1: {
        name: "Text",
        type: 'text',
        value: "Hello World",
        events: {
          keyup: function(e) {
            window.console && console.log('key: ' + e.keyCode);
          }
        }
      }
    },
    events: {
      show: function(opt) {
        var $this = this;
        $.contextMenu.setInputValues(opt, $this.data());
        
        // Set focus to the input element
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('[name="context-menu-input-input1"]').focus();
        }, 10);
      },
      hide: function(opt) {
        var $this = this;
        $.contextMenu.getInputValues(opt, $this.data());
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/dist/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<span class="context-menu-one btn btn-neutral">right click me</span>
```

Hope this helps.